# Can i somehow declare variable as query result?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have stored procedure which should use count of records in table, lets name it table1.
I know i can:

```
select count(*) 
  into variable_name 
  from table1
```

but i really want to keep procedure body as clean and simple as possible.
Can i put this query into declaration and set value of my variable as result of the query in the declaration section?

Comment: As name said to Declaration, mean this area is not for execution of Query, we have execution part within "BEGIN END". And this is not a bad design if you write select statement within BEGIN --- END;

Comment: One of the options is to move the whole query into a separate function, e.g. `variable_name = count_table1();`. This particular query doesn't look *that* dirty for me though.

Comment: separate function may be the one i need, but i really want to know if i am able to do it without any additional objects

Comment: Actually I find it much cleaner to have the query in the body, rather than have to switch back and forth between declaration and body to see what's actually happening. It's also leaner and easier to read in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is there is no syntax to embed an implicit cursor within a declaration. The general syntax for declaring a variable or constant is:

```
identifier [constant] datatype := expression;
```

`expression` can be a function, for example:

```
k_somecount constant integer := some_lookup('whatever');
```

That might be a neat approach if the function is used in multiple places or has multiple steps etc.

I wondered if there was a way to use an XML expression, for example:

```
k_somecount constant integer := cast(xmlwhatever(mystic xquery incantation) as integer);
```

but it seems not (and if there was, I don't think you would like it).

**There is no implicit cursor expression syntax such as the following:**

```
-- Made-up syntax purely to illustrate what you might have been hoping existed:
k_somecount integer := (select count(*) from employees);
```

Answer (score 1):

As Vivek and default Locale mentioned, a `Select` within a pl/sql-block (like funcitons or procedures) is totally ok.

But there is one place where i do it: We store create-scripts for automated integration-tests in plsql-scripts.

To make them readable they look like this:

```
DECLARE
    sqlCreateTable   VARCHAR2 (2000) :=
'CREATE TABLE TMyTableName
(
  COL1        VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)             NOT NULL,
  COL2        VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)             NOT NULL
)
TABLESPACE MYTABLESPACE
PCTUSED    0
PCTFREE    0
INITRANS   1
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
            INITIAL          1M
            NEXT             1M
            MINEXTENTS       1
            MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
            PCTINCREASE      0
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
           )
LOGGING 
NOCOMPRESS 
NOCACHE
MONITORING';

    sqlCreateIndex   VARCHAR2 (2000) :=
'CREATE UNIQUE 
    [...]
)';

    sqlCreateView    VARCHAR2 (2000) := 
'CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW VMyTable
(
    COL1,
    COL2
)
    BEQUEATH DEFINER
AS
    SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM
      FROM MyTableName';
BEGIN
    -- |---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
    -- | CREATE TABLE                                                              |
    -- |---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
    dbms_output.put_line('- - - - - - START - - - - - -'); 
    dbms_output.put_line('CREATE TABLE:' || chr(10) || sqlCreateTable); 
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlCreateTable;

    dbms_output.put_line('CREATE INDEX:' || chr(10) || sqlCreateIndex); 
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlCreateIndex;

    dbms_output.put_line('CREATE VIEW:' || chr(10) || sqlCreateView); 
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlCreateView;

    dbms_output.put_line('- - - - - - DONE - - - - - -'); 
END;
```

Short example to run a query and populate local variables:

```
DECLARE
    myQuery   VARCHAR2 (2000) := 'SELECT 1 from DUAL';
    myVar     NUMBER;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE myQuery INTO myVar;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('MyVar: ' || myVar);
END;
```

Comment: I don't see any functions.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson corrected the sentence. "Within a plsql-block (like functions or procedures)"

Comment: I don't see any lookup evaluated as part of declaration, which is surely what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I don't understand what you're saying (i'm not a native english-speaker). This is my solution for keeping scripts readable. The workflow is kept clean, by moving long statements to the declaration.

Comment: Andrew is looking for a way to populate `variable_name` with the result of a query as part of its declaration, e.g. `declare variable_name integer := what_should_go_here?;` I don't see what this answer has to do with the question.

Comment: Ah. Didn't think about, that it could be a problem to add this. Added a short example which populates a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this,

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR c 
    IS   SELECT last_name, first_name 
           FROM employee;
    TYPE emp_tab IS TABLE OF c%ROWTYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
    v_emp_tab emp_tab;
    v_variable_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
    OPEN c;
    FETCH c BULK COLLECT INTO v_emp_tab;
    v_variable_count := v_emp_tab.COUNT;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_variable_count);
    CLOSE c;
END;
/
```

Comment: that looks like even more code needed to reach my goal, but still thank you for you solution, i kinda forgot about cursors and that i can declare one

Comment: This doesn't seem to meet the requirement to include the query to initialise the variable within its declaration.